# uninitialized constant (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have seen few similar questions here on SO but none of the given solutions work. I have installed rspec/factorygirl as usual and i'm facing some problems i can't understand. It seems that rspec can't see my models.

#### Gefile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'faker'
end

group :test do
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

I have run `rails generate rspec:install` to generate the `spec/` dir file structure (so my spec_helper and rails_helper files contains the proper lines with environment require etc.)

#### spec/models/list_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe List do
  before(:each) do
    @list = FactoryGirl.build(:list)
  end

  it 'is invalid without name' do
    @list.title = nil
    expect(@list).to_not be_valid
  end
end
```

#### spec_helper.rb

https://gist.github.com/mbajur/68e96ab77f43d50a73cf

#### rails_helper.rb

https://gist.github.com/mbajur/677c9936347be8b18c7d

#### list_factory.rb

https://gist.github.com/mbajur/49668f280891fa80f288

And when i run `rspec`, it gives me `uninitialized constant List (NameError)` on line 3 of `list_spec.rb` file.

Comment: What's in your `spec_helper.rb`?

Comment: I have added that to original question, please have a look

Comment: just change `describe List do ...` to `describe 'List' do ...`.

Comment: well, that partially resolves my problem but there is still something rong with my setup. Right now my specs can't see FactoryGirl (unitialized constant FactoryGirl)

Comment: because you not `require` `factory_girl_rails` in `spec_helper` or in `rails_helper`.

Comment: You're right. But after requireing it, factory_girl can't see my factories. I've been setting that up hundred of times and that's a first time i'm experiencing such problems...

Comment: @mbajur please post in question body your actual factories and helpers file with all `require`ing what you make.

Comment: I have added factory yto the original question. However, do i need to somehow require it manually? I've never been doing such thing in my previous apps, factories were allways 'visible' automatically...

Comment: why you need two `_helper` files?

Comment: I'm not sure, they were generated by `rails generate rspec:install` task. Anyway, i have fixed that (all the problems mentioned in question and comments) by requireing rails_helper instead of spec_helper everywhere. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Change `describe List do ...` to `describe 'List' do ...` and be sure what you require all needed lib in helper file and leave one `_helper.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was caused by the fact that i was requireing `spec_helper` in all my specs while i should require `rails_helper`.

So, each spec file should start with the following line:

```
require 'rails_helper`
```